# AMP Server Publish Ready False. http://localhost:8200/

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm

Getting response. i attached kibana response

{
"build_date": "2024-02-01T10:06:19Z",
"build_sha": "53446838048a050511b9ef1b7921806e5accbea1",
"publish_ready": false,
"version": "8.12.1"
}

[image]

[image]

I need solution everything is fine then why not true publish ready.